# YouTube higher quality = no buffering

Tags: youtube

While watching videos (no video in particular) if the video starts buffering at 360p, I switch to 240p and it still buffers but if I switch to 480p it doesn't. I'm connected directly to a router so signal variation should not be an issue.

This happens on all desktop platforms I have tried. I used Chrome for all of them.

How come?

Comment: Could you please share the link? And which OS / browser?

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe the video is natively 480p, so it doesn't need any conversions if you view it in that resolution.

Comment: @peter There is no particular video and this happens on all desktop platforms I have tried. I used chrome for all of them

Answer (score 0):

For improved buffering of 480p videos on YouTube try enabling the YouTube HTML5 Video Player at this [link](https://www.youtube.com/html5).

Comment: agovizer said in a comment below the original question *There is no particular video and this happens on all desktop platforms I have tried.* YouTube HTML5 Video Player buffers better than Adobe Flash Player on all platforms.

Comment: No, actually it's the exact opposite. Because YouTube HTML5 Video Player has **improved buffering** it buffers for a longer time along the YouTube video timeline which results in a smooth uninterrupted video playback and no stuttering due to inadequate buffering. Basically I think you read the question backwards, because the question makes less sense except for the way I interpreted it.

Comment: Because the question is unclear my answer isn't wrong. It's just a matter of how one reads an unclear question.